# can create an isolated internal network in the vcenter distribute switch?

Tags: vmware, vsphere, vcenter

I just want to know whether we can add an isolated internal network in the vcenter distribute switch?
One vm have a dhcp server.
Will it effect the public network?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this VMware KB article](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2043160).  You're required to have the virtual machines on the same host for it to work.  In such case, it might be easier just to create a standard vSwitch with no uplink adapters.